# Observables and fetching paged data?

Tags: rxjs

I need to create an observable, which I can "pull" data from, to work with a pageable api. I can only fetch 100 items per request, I want to be able to use observable as a generator function (on which I can call `.next()` to issue a request to get next 100 items. 
I can't unfortunately find a way to do it with Rx. I suppose it's possible using controlled observable or a subject. Can you guys show me an example.

this is what I've gotten so far:

```
function list(entityType, viewName, fetchAll = false) {
    var skip = 0,
        total = 0;

    const subject = new Rx.Subject(),
        response$ = subject
        .takeWhile(() => skip <= total)
        .startWith(skip)
        .flatMap((skip) => fetchPagePromise(skip)),

        next = () => subject.onNext(skip);

    if (fetchAll) {
        Rx.Observable.timer(100, 100).subscribe(() => next());
    }

    return {
        data$: response$.map(response => response),
        next: fetchAll === true ? undefined : next
    };

    function fetchPagePromise() {
        let limit = 100,
            obj = {
                viewName, limit, skip
            },
            qs = objectToQueryString(obj);

        return $http.get(`${apiBase}/api/data/${entityType}${qs}`).then((res) => {
            total = res.data.Total;
            skip += limit;

            return res.data.Rows;
        });
    }
}
```

this kinda works like a generator. it returns an Observable and `next` handler. Whenever `next` is called it pulls next 100 items from api and pushes into the Observable. Also if there’s a third parameter `fetchAll` passed, then it will keep fetching data until there’s no more. What scares me though that there are 2 mutating vars in function's closure - `skip` and `total`, and I don't know if managing them like this in asynchronous/unpredictable environment is ok.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you have tried? How do you plan to trigger a `next` request? What does your pageable api look like?

Comment: @paulpdaniels I included a code snippet

Answer (score 2):

One of the things you generally want to avoid is trying to make Rx into a plain old event emitter. Usually it is an indicator when you try and just trigger `Observables` manually by passing around a `Subjects` observer interface.

You should ask yourself, where is my data coming from? What calls `next()`, what calls that, etc. After enough of these you will generally find that this will lead you to something that can be wrapped by an `Observable` directly rather than explicitly calling `next()`. Also, I think the `fetchAll` flag should really be kept externally. You are only making the interface confusing by essentially turning it into a void method just by passing in a flag.

So I would recommend refactoring like so:

```
Rx.Observable.prototype.lazyRequest = function(entityType, viewName, limit = 100) {
  var source = this;
  return Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
    var response = source
                     //Skip is really just the (limit * index) 
                     .map((x, i) => i * limit)
                     .flatMap((skip) => {
                               let obj = {viewName, skip, limit},
                                   qs = objectToQueryString(obj);

                               //Handle promises implicitly
                               return $http.get(`${apiBase}/api/data/${entityType}${qs}`);
                              },
                              //Return this with our skip information
                              (skip, res) => {skip, res})
                     //Publish it so the stream get shared.
                     .publish();

    //This will emit once once you are out of data
    var stop = response.first(x => x.skip >= x.res.data.Total);

    return new CompositeDisposable(
      //Complete this stream when stop emits
      response.takeUntil(stop)
              //Downstream only cares about the data rows
              .map(x => x.res.data.Rows)
              .subscribe(obs),
      //Hook everything up
      response.connect());

  });

}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
//An example of a "starting point", a button click
//Update the rows every time a new event comes through
Rx.Observable.fromEvent($button, 'click')
             .startWith(0) //Inject some data into the pipeline
             .lazyRequest(entityType, viewName)
             .subscribe(/*Do something with the returned rows*/);

//Get all of the rows, will keep hitting the endpoint until it completes
Rx.Observable.interval(100)
             .lazyRequest(entityType, viewName)
             //Gather all the values into an array and emit that.
             .toArray()
             .subscribe();
```